# Find neighbouring polygons R

Tags: r, coordinates

I have one table containing +500k rows with coordinates `x`, `y` grouped by `shapeid` (289 ids in total) and forming a polygon.

```
shapeid      x           y
1            679400.3   6600354
1            679367.9   6600348
1            679313.3   6600340
1            679259.5   6600331
1            679087.5   6600201
0            661116.3   6606615
0            661171.5   6606604
0            661182.7   6606605
0            661198.9   6606606
0            661205.9   6606605
...          ...        ...
```

I want to find the coordinates which intersects or lies closest to each other, **in essence finding the physical neighbours for each shapeid**.

The results should look something like:

```
shapeid shapeid_neighbour1   shapeid_neighbour2
```

So I tried using sp and rgeos like so:

```
library(sp)
library(rgeos)

mydata <- read.delim('d:/temp/testfile.txt', header=T, sep=",")

sp.mydata <- mydata
coordinates(sp.mydata) <- ~x+y
```

When I run class, everything looks fine:

```
class(sp.mydata)
[1] "SpatialPointsDataFrame"
attr(,"package")
[1] "sp"
```

I now try calculating the distance by each point:

```
d <- gDistance(sp.mydata, byid=T)
```

**R Studio encounters fatal error. Any ideas?** My plan is then to use:

```
min.d <- apply(d, 1, function(x) order(x, decreasing=F)[2])
```

To find the second shortest distance, i.e. the closest point. But maybe this isn't the best approach to do what I want - finding the physical neighbours for each shapeid?

Comment: Are you really interested in min(euclidean distance) between the shapes? Usually SHP represent geometries on the Earth's ellipsoid.

Comment: Back to the topic of your question. You are computing a distance matrix between the polygons; a 100k by 100k may be well over your RAM. You can try computing and saving this matrix into a file row-by-row.

Comment: You've created a `SpatialPOINTSDataFrame` from all the vertices of your polygons. You need `SpatialPOLYGONS`. Research how to build spatialPolygons from a set of 2-column matrices, then you can use functions in package `spdep` to compute the adjacency.

Comment: I'm interested in the best option to determine which shapeids are each others physical neighbours under above circumstances

Comment: Are you sure that the polygons aren't intersecting with each other? Are they disjoint?

Comment: rgeos is the thing, but you really should build and compute with polygons because vertex distance is insufficient to infer polygon distance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that each `shapeid` of your dataframe identifies the vertices of a polygon, you need first to create a `SpatialPolygons` object from the coordinates and then apply the function `gDistance` to know the distance between any pair of polygons (assuming that is what you are looking for). In order to create a `SpatialPolygons` you need a `Polygons` and in turn a `Polygon` object. You can find details in the help page of the `sp` package under `Polygon`.

You might find soon a problem: the coordinates of each polygons must close, i.e. the last vertex must be the same as the first for each shapeid. As far as I can see from your data, that seems not to be the case for you. So you should "manually" add a row for each subset of your data.

You can try this (assuming that `df` is your starting dataframe):

```
    require(rgeos)
    #split the dataframe for each shapeid and coerce to matrix
    coordlist<-lapply(split(df[,2:3],df$shapeid),as.matrix)
    #apply the following command only if the polygons don't close
    #coordlist<-lapply(coordilist, function(x) rbind(x,x[1,]))
    #create a SpatialPolygons for each shapeid
    SPList<-lapply(coordlist,function(x) SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(Polygon(x)),1))))
    #initialize a matrix of distances
    distances<-matrix(0,ncol=length(SPList),nrow=length(SPList))
    #calculate the distances
    for (i in 1:(length(SPList)-1))
      for (j in (i+1):length(SPList))
        distances[i,j]<-gDistance(SPList[[i]],SPList[[j]])
```

This may require some time, since you are calculating 289*288/2 polygons distances. Eventually, you'll obtain a matrix of distances.

Comment: I'm pretty sure one of the spatial packages has a function to shortcut all that "list of polys of lists of spatial lists of" when building a single ring from a coordinate matrix but I can never remember what it is and its easy enough to write anyway...

Comment: Realizing it would be difficult to answer in general terms, but how long would you estimate this calculation to take? I have 8gb RAM and I5-2400 CPU @ 3.10ghz

Comment: It depends on how much complicated are your polygons, but I think that a couple of minutes should suffice. However, you can start the loop inside a `system.time()`, stop it whenever you want, and then multiply the time you obtain by `289*288/2/(sum(289-1:(i-1))+j-i)` to have an educated guess.