# Find nearest neighbours of polygons in R

Tags: r, spatial, r-sf

I have a data frame with coordinates that I have converted to a sf object in R like this:

```
> head(df1)
  Cell_ID   Spot_ID       X       Y
1       0 600000000 193.722 175.733
2       0 600000001 192.895 176.727
3       0 600000002 193.828 177.462
4       8 600000003 178.173 178.220
5       7 600000004 187.065 178.285
6       0 600000005 190.754 178.186

> df1_sf <- st_as_sf(df1,
                     coords = c('X', 'Y')) %>%
    group_by(Cell_ID) %>%
    summarise() %>%
    ungroup() %>%  
    st_convex_hull()
>plot(st_geometry(df1_sf), border = "red")
```

I can then plot all my polygons and it looks like this:
[image]

Now I would like to get the ID of the neighbours of each polygons. To do so I am doing

```
n = st_set_geometry(st_intersection(df1_sf,df1_sf), NULL)
head(n)
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  Cell_ID Cell_ID.1
    <int>     <int>
1       0         0
2       7         0
3      51         0
4       1         1
5       4         1
6       5         1
```

But this is doing a mediocre job because it needs an intersection whereas I am also interested in them if they are the closest one (close although not touching like in the picture bellow, Cell_ID 1 will have as neighbours cells 3-6 but will also detect cell 7 because it is in a given radius for example).
Could anyone help me with this problem?

Thanks !!
[image]

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by a 'neighbour' ? In your example picture, should polygon 2 also be counted as a neighbour? And do you want to include 7, or exclude 7? What about the polygon that's between 6 & 7?

Comment: sorry, so the neighbours for polygon 1 are : 2,3,4,5,6 as st_intersect will pick, but I want to also add 7 because, although not intersecting, it is in a close radius.

Comment: Could [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53854803/calculate-minimum-distance-between-multiple-polygons-with-r) be of interest? Or possible using non overlapping join like `st_join(x, y, st_is_within_distance, dist = some_distance)`?

Also a similar answer to a similar question but using `sp` package [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25761315/find-neighbouring-polygons-r?rq=1)

Comment: You could `sf::st_buffer()` each polygon to expand the borders out to your required 'radius', then find all those borders which touch?

Comment: That's a great idea. I thought about that too but didn't know how to do it. Trying it now, looks promising !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To illustrate the excellent suggestion of using a buffer around each polygon
(mathematical dilation of each polygon) here is a quick and dirty `spatstat`
solution.

First load the package and make some example data:

```r
library(spatstat)
dat <- tiles(dirichlet(cells))
ii <- seq(2, 42, by=2)
dat[ii] <- lapply(dat[ii], erosion, r = .01)
dat <- lapply(seq_along(dat), function(i) cbind(Cell_ID = i, as.data.frame(dat[[i]])))
dat <- Reduce(rbind, dat)
df1 <- cbind(Spot_ID = 1:nrow(dat), dat)
head(df1)
#>   Spot_ID Cell_ID         x         y
#> 1       1       1 0.4067780 0.0819020
#> 2       2       1 0.3216680 0.1129640
#> 3       3       1 0.1967080 0.0000000
#> 4       4       1 0.4438430 0.0000000
#> 5       5       2 0.5630909 0.1146781
#> 6       6       2 0.4916145 0.1649979
```

Split for each `Cell_ID`, find convex hull and plot the data:

```r
dat <- split(df1[,c("x", "y")], df1$Cell_ID)
dat <- lapply(dat, convexhull)
plot(owin(), main = "")
for(i in seq_along(dat)){
  plot(dat[[i]], add = TRUE, border = "red")
}
```

[image]

Dilate each polygon:

```r
bigdat <- lapply(dat, dilation, r = 0.0125)
```

Make a naive for-loop assigning which dilated polygons overlap (i.e. full
n^2 pairwise intersections):

```r
neigh <- list()
for(i in seq_along(bigdat)){
  overlap <- sapply(bigdat[-i], function(x) !is.empty(intersect.owin(x, bigdat[[i]])))
  neigh[[i]] <- which(overlap)
}
```

Plot dilated polygons with number of neighbours (ids of neighbours are in
the list `neigh`):

```r
plot(owin(), main = "")
for(i in seq_along(bigdat)){
  plot(bigdat[[i]], add = TRUE, border = "red")
}
text.ppp(cells, labels = sapply(neigh, length))
```

[image]

### Alternative tessellation based solution

Is it an requirement to use the convexhull as the definition of the cell
areas? I would be tempted to simply represent each cell by the centroid of
the sample points and then use the Dirichlet/Voronoi tesselation as the
regions. These have well-defined neighbours everywhere and the only issue is
how to define the bounding region of the collection of cells.

Split for each `Cell_ID`, find centroid, tessellate and plot the data:

```r
dat <- split(df1[,c("x", "y")], df1$Cell_ID)
dat <- t(sapply(dat, colMeans))
X <- as.ppp(dat, W = ripras)
D <- dirichlet(X)
plot(D)
```

[image]

Extra code to find neighbour ids:

```r
eps <- sqrt(.Machine$double.eps) # Epsilon for numerical comparison below
tilelist <- tiles(D)
v_list <- lapply(tilelist, vertices.owin)
v_list <- lapply(v_list, function(v){ppp(v$x, v$y, window = Window(X), check = FALSE)})
neigh <- list()
dd <- safedeldir(X)
for(i in seq_len(npoints(X))){
  ## All neighbours from deldir (infinite border tiles)
  all_neigh <- c(dd$delsgs$ind1[dd$delsgs$ind2==i],
                 dd$delsgs$ind2[dd$delsgs$ind1==i])
  ## The remainder keeps only neighbour tiles that share a vertex with tile i:
  true_neigh <- sapply(v_list[all_neigh], function(x){min(nncross.ppp(v_list[[i]], x))}) < eps
  neigh[[i]] <- sort(all_neigh[true_neigh])
}
plot(D, main = "Tessellation with Cell_ID")
text(X)
```

[image]

```r
neigh[[1]] # Neighbours of tile 1
#> [1] 2 7 8
neigh[[10]] # Neighbours of tile 10
#> [1]  3  4  5  9 15 16 20
```

Comment: Thanks, I am just having trouble to reproduce this using my initial data that is a dataframe with 4 columns: Cell_ID, spots_IDs, X, Y, Z

Comment: Could you please provide some example data to test on?

Comment: A section of the data : dput(df_80k[1:12,])
structure(list(Cell_ID = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 7L, 0L, 8L, 0L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 8L), Spot_ID = 600000000:600000011, X = c(193.722, 192.895, 
193.828, 178.173, 187.065, 190.754, 176.811, 192.296, 183.826, 
187.678, 189.421, 179.755), Y = c(175.733, 176.727, 177.462, 
178.22, 178.285, 178.186, 178.739, 178.648, 178.79, 178.963, 
179.012, 179.347), Z = c(0.0998975, 0.0998975, 0.0998975, 0.0998975, 
0.0998975, 0.0998975, 0.0998975, 0.0998975, 0.0998975, 0.0998975, 
0.0998975, 0.0998975)), row.names = c(NA, 12L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: Well @Amaranta_Remedios, it was hard to illustrate the procedure with the data for three polygons you provided in the comment. Instead I tried to make my artificial data closer to your data, so `df1` is in a similar format as yours and you should be able to run the code with small modifications such as `X` instead of `x`. What do you think about the tessellation solution?

Comment: Thanks, The problem is I realised that I just picked the first n in the data frame, so the points were not necessarily connected, thanks for still helping. Your solution seems amazing. Got some weird error ```Error: Attempted to create binary mask with 6771 * 3836 = 25973556 entries In addition: Warning messages:
1: Window occupies only 0.0031% of frame area. Did you mean owin(poly=df) ? 
2: Window occupies only 0.01% of frame area. Did you mean owin(poly=df) ? ```

Comment: Well it is impossible to say what is happening here without access to your data. The warning seems safe to ignore. The error regarding binary masks seems strange. We should do everything which polygons here and not image mask approximations.

Comment: Original data here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QIIy57abSTisFT-Wmvxrx7itpqbFbYYat5BLMrv-t9Y/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

From your question it seems you are more interested in a generic *nearest neighbour* type approach. Please correct me if this is an oversimplification.

Rather than considering each polygon and its borders you could simply take the central coordinate and use any `knn` type algorithm to classify `k nearest neighbours` to a given coordinate.

Since I do not have access to your data I have created some dummy coordinates.
Using package `RANN` and function `nn2` [see here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/RANN/versions/2.6.1/topics/nn2).

```
install.packages('RANN')
library(RANN)

# Make dummy coordinates
df <- 
  data.frame(   X = runif(100)
              , Y = runif(100)
               )

# Find closest 5 points between df and itself
closest <- nn2(data = df, query = df , k = 5)

closest$nn.idx # Index of Closest neigbours
closest$nn.dists # Euclidean distance of Closest neigbours

# Note the first colum is a reference to itself, so real 5 nearest neighbours (not including itself) would mean you select k = 6.

> head(closest$nn.idx) # Euclidean distance of Closest neigbours
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1   82   31   86   49
[2,]    2   22   41   34   91
[3,]    3   96   20   55   32
[4,]    4   65   53   77   14
[5,]    5   38   48   59   30
[6,]    6   36   43   97   61

> head(closest$nn.dists) # Euclidean distance of Closest neigbours
     [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]
[1,]    0 0.04971692 0.06305752 0.08597908 0.09485483
[2,]    0 0.03668956 0.05248395 0.09570358 0.10489092
[3,]    0 0.07257007 0.10263107 0.11204297 0.13275642
[4,]    0 0.07209561 0.07227328 0.07259919 0.07326718
[5,]    0 0.02842711 0.06003873 0.08930219 0.12286905
[6,]    0 0.08018734 0.09312385 0.10844622 0.11368332
```

You can also do this based on a radius approach mentioned in your question using `searchtype = "radius"` and `radius`.

Comment: Thanks, 
That's a great suggestion but unfortunately I can't use the centre points nor just the closest neighbours because the points come from biological data (cells) and I need to find touching neighbours (contact membrane to membrane). Which is why I am trying to treat each cell as a polygon.

Comment: Ah I understand, however when you say "contact membrane to membrane" you want to allow some margin since you would like cell 7 to still be a neighbour even though it is NOT in contact?

Comment: Yes, exactly, I want to allow a little margin (example 2 um) so that everything inside that margin is called a neighbour.